# jQuery Validate plugin submitHandler delaying form submit

Tags: jquery, forms, post, jquery-validate

I am using jQuery Validate plugin's `submitHandler` to disable Submit Button, but once form submitted button is disabled and I have to wait like good 5 - 10 seconds before form will be POSTED to other page? Whole Code below, very strange? It maybe something with time-out ?

```
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/jquery.validate.js"></script>
        <script src="http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/additional-methods.js"></script>   

        <script>

        $( "#UploadForm" ).validate({

  errorLabelContainer: "#messageBox",
  wrapper: "td",

  rules: {  

   name: {
        required: true
         }

  },
  submitHandler: function (form) {

   $('#submit').attr('disabled','disabled');
   form.submit();

}

});
        </script>
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`$('#UploadForm').submit();` triggers another round of validation ("too much recursion error" documented here: http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/)

Try this:

```
submitHandler: function (form) {
   $('#submit').attr('disabled','disabled');
   form.submit();
}
```

Comment: This works for me. Using `$('#UploadForm').submit();` gives "too much recursion error" as documented. Try to host the `jquery.validate.js` file local, including `http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/jquery.validate.js` does not work for me

Comment: Download it to the same folder as your html file and include with `<script src="./jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript">`