# Submit handler is working but its very slow

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Hello guys I am submitting my form using submit handler and its working but its very slow. Please help me to make it fast. Thanks in advance
Following is my javascript code for login form......

```
       var handleLoginForm = function () {

       $('.login-form').validate({
        errorElement: 'label', //default input error message container
        errorClass: 'help-inline', // default input error message class
        focusInvalid: false, // do not focus the last invalid input
        rules: {
            username: {
                required: true
            },
            password: {
                required: true
            },
             user_type: {
                required: true
            },
            remember: {
                required: false
            }
        },

        messages: {
            username: {
                required: "Username is required."
            },
            password: {
                required: "Password is required."
            },
              user_type: {
                required: "User Type is Required."
            }
        },

        invalidHandler: function (event, validator) { //display error alert on form submit   
            $('.alert-error', $('.login-form')).show();
        },

        highlight: function (element) { // hightlight error inputs
            $(element)
                .closest('.control-group').addClass('error'); // set error class to the control group
        },
        data: $('#form_modulesadd').serialize(),

        success: function (label) {
            label.closest('.control-group').removeClass('error');
            label.remove();
        },

        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
            error.addClass('help-small no-left-padding').insertAfter(element.closest('.input-icon'));
        },

           submitHandler: function (form) {
           $( ".login-form input" ).submit();
            window.location.href = "check.php";

        }
    });
```

It was fast when i was submitting the form using php but I must have to use javascript to submit this form......

Comment: Could you be a little more specific?  Is it a server/connection issue?  is your form huge?  It could be 1000 things

Comment: it was very fast when i was using php. but here i must have to use javascript and it become slow. its a login form.

Comment: Try running the JS when the form is submitted. Now you seem to have it in a function, but call it like this: `$(".login-form").submit(function(){ ... });` It might help with the speed.

Comment: You've told us that "it" is "very slow". Unfortunately, that doesn't provide much information about what the problem might be. Indeed, it could be thousands of things. If you want an answer that is more than just a guess, please describe what you mean by "it" and "very slow". For example, with what part of the form submission are you observing a problem? Is it a client side issue or a server side issue... etc.

Comment: Basic debugging here people, Use your browser to find where the lag is.. Use console.log with timestamps or further use the inspector of your browser and monitor / audit the network and content..

Comment: @Mayhem is right, but better practice is using `console.time` and `console.timeEnd` pair for that (see https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console-api#consoletimelabel) - the first one at the beginning of time interval to be measured and the second one at its ending.

Comment: Hello Hexturtle,
Actually I am submitting login form and redirecting it to check.php where i am checking username password and redirecting accordingly.

Comment: **You should not be submitting the form and navigating away by setting the location!** The end result will NOT do what you want.

Comment: Hello epascarello, you are right. by doing this my javascript is not working on the next page.
by applying "$(".login-form").submit(function(){ ... });" to the code my javascript is not working on the redirected page. but before that it was working but it was very slow

Comment: Hello @epascarello, Do you have any solution....????

Comment: Try this.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18041140/jquery-validate-plugin-submithandler-delaying-form-submit

Answer (score 0):

Run the JS when the form is submitted:

```
$(".login-form").submit(function(){
 $('.login-form').validate({
        errorElement: 'label', //default input error message container
        errorClass: 'help-inline', // default input error message class
        focusInvalid: false, // do not focus the last invalid input
        rules: {
            username: {
                required: true
            },
            password: {
                required: true
            },
             user_type: {
                required: true
            },
            remember: {
                required: false
            }
        },

        messages: {
            username: {
                required: "Username is required."
            },
            password: {
                required: "Password is required."
            },
              user_type: {
                required: "User Type is Required."
            }
        },

        invalidHandler: function (event, validator) { //display error alert on form submit   
            $('.alert-error', $('.login-form')).show();
        },

        highlight: function (element) { // hightlight error inputs
            $(element)
                .closest('.control-group').addClass('error'); // set error class to the control group
        },
        data: $('#form_modulesadd').serialize(),

        success: function (label) {
            label.closest('.control-group').removeClass('error');
            label.remove();
        },

        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
            error.addClass('help-small no-left-padding').insertAfter(element.closest('.input-icon'));
        },

           submitHandler: function (form) {
           $( ".login-form input" ).submit();
            window.location.href = "check.php";

        }
    });
});
```

This keeps the JS from running until the form is submitted.
UPDATE:

```
$(".login_form").submit(function(){
  $(this).validate({ ... });
});
```

Not sure if this will work, but the repeated selector seemed a bit awkward to me.

Comment: Hello, you are right. by doing this my javascript is not working on the next page. by applying "$(".login-form").submit(function(){ ... });" to the code my javascript is not working on the redirected page. but before that it was working but it was very slow

Comment: Hello @Tricks For The Web, by applying your code my javascript is not working on the redirecting page. Please help me.

Comment: What do you mean by "redirecting page"?

Comment: If you copied and pasted my code, I used an underscore `_` instead of a dash `-`... see edit.

Comment: Hello @Tricks for the Web, Its submitting and redirecting to the exact page fastly. But on the redirected page javascript(responsive navbar and responsive tabs) is not working. I am using bootstrap(metronic) design template

Answer (score 0):

I solved the same problem by changing the implementation of submitHandler like below. I just take the first item [0] of the forms selector.

```
submitHandler: function (form) {
    $(".login-form input")[0].submit();
    ...
}
```